# Visual Studio 2012 Intelli-sense isn't working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

ok, i'm not sure how to say this but you know how when you type something it will have a dropdown menu of possible things you might be trying to do, like when you type in #include

Answer (score 0):

If you start to type something, and then press `CTRL + Space` it will show code completion suggestions.  If  that still does not work then you should probably restart the instance of visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Space. or. Ctrl + J.  or Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard and check what is assigned to these shortcuts. The command name should be Edit.CompleteWord